# Transpose dynamic table from rows to columns and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
config.previewData = [
    {
        Cartridges:27989,
        Total Accounts:294,
        Metrices:"MVC",
        Toner Cartridges:5928,
        INK Cartridges:22061
    },
    {
        Cartridges:56511,
        Total Accounts:376,
        Metrices:"SMB",
        Toner Cartridges:15253,
        INK Cartridges:41258
    },
    {
        Cartridges:84,500,
        Total Accounts:670,
        Metrices:"Grand Total",
        Toner Cartridges:21,181,
        INK Cartridges:63,319
    },
]
```

and my html code like this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in config.previewData[0]">
                {{ key}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in config.previewData">
            <td data-ng-repeat="column in row">
                {{column}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this code will print perfect like below image
[image]

now i want to transpose this table into rows to columns and columns to rows. 
Is this possible with dynamic table because my object is dynamic not fixed.

Help me if anyone knows how to do this.
After transpose table looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same assumptions your example codes does (i.e. `config.previewData` always contains at least one object, and all objects have the same properties...)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in config.previewData[0]">
            <th>
                {{ key }}
            </th>
            <td data-ng-repeat="row in config.previewData">
                {{ row[key] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can have something like this to transpose your data, which can then be used to iterate over using `ng-repeat` very easily!

Example snippet (in Pure JS for simplification):

```js
var previewData = [{
    "Cartridges": 27989,
    "Total Accounts": 294,
    "Metrices": "MVC",
    "Toner Cartridges": 5928,
    "INK Cartridges": 22061
  },
  {
    "Cartridges": 56511,
    "Total Accounts": 376,
    "Metrices": "SMB",
    "Toner Cartridges": 15253,
    "INK Cartridges": 41258
  },
  {
    "Cartridges": 84500,
    "Total Accounts": 670,
    "Metrices": "Grand Total",
    "Toner Cartridges": 21181,
    "INK Cartridges": 63319
  }
]

var transpose = previewData.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      arr[key] = arr[key] || []
      arr[key].push(obj[key])
    }
  }
  return arr
}, {})

console.log(transpose)
```

Comment: @dkc007 just replace normal variables with scope variables. Pure JS is used just for simplicity here

Answer (score 0):

this is the only (dirty) way i could think out

```
<tr>
        <td data-ng-repeat="row in previewData">{{row['Metrices']}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-ng-repeat="row in previewData">{{row['Total Accounts']}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-ng-repeat="row in previewData">{{row['Toner Cartridges']}}</td>
    </tr>
```

...... and so on

other options: [Transposing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940605/transposing-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2-D array which can be logged  into console by the function

```
 tab = [[2,3,4],[-4,6,0],[1,0,9]]
 console.table(tab)
```

You can log the transpose of it by using the following function:

```
function transpose_table(tab) {
    let columns = tab.length;
    let rows = tab[0].length;
    
    let trans = [];
    
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        trans.push([]);
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<columns; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<rows; j++) {
            trans[j][i] = tab[i][j];
        }
    }

    return trans;
}
```

Now run:

```
console.table(transpose_table(tab))
```

Comment: Please explain the code as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).